# PHP - How to authenticate with active directory when server is in cloud

Tags: php, laravel, azure, active-directory

I have a laravel 5.1 app and I have implemented active directory authentication. This works on localhost when I connect the network cable of the company to my computer. However, the production server is on Microsoft Azure and not on the company server. How can I make the authentication work in such a case?

Comment: Are you using a package for this? If so, which package?

Comment: I am not using a package

Comment: Well just like every computer in a network that authenticates to an AD will need to have the IP or DNS name of the AD. I guess your application has some sort of configuration regarding the IP or DNS as well? Just change that to the IP or DNS name of your AD in Microsoft Azure and you should be fine. Maybe there is a firewall active so make sure that you are allowed to contact the AD.

Comment: Hi @ThomasSnijder. Thanks for your input. I just talked to system team and they said there is no link between the Azure network and our local network and that such a link is under construction.  Are they any work around.

Comment: may i confirm that now your app server is in cloud , then you want to login with your active directory account ?

Comment: Hi @Nan Yu  yes.  It's working in localhost on my computer since my PC is connected to the company network. But the test server is on Azure

Comment: I'm not an expert on Azure so I am not able to tell you if there are any other ways of connecting to an AD on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with on-premises Active Directory in your Azure app , you could :

1.Authenticate through Azure Active Directory

An Azure Active Directory tenant can be directory-synced with an on-premises AD. This approach enables AD users to access your App from the internet and authenticate using their on-premises credentials. Azure Active Directory tenant can be [synced with your on-premise Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) to create a single sign-on experience for workers that are on-premises and remote.

2.Authenticate through an on-premises STS

If you have an on-premises secure token service (STS) like Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS), you can use that to federate authentication for your Azure app/

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-authentication-authorization) for more details .